# How to set currency code to <lightning:input type="number" formatter="currency">

Tags: lightning-aura-components, multi-currency, currency, lightninginput

I am developing a custom currency field with [lightning:input type="number" formatter="currency"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleInputNumber) component:

```
<lightning:input type="number" formatter="currency" value="100" step="1"/>
```

I have enabled in my org the `Multiple Currencies` feature so each record's amounts can be declared with different currencies

This means that sometimes my custom field will contain USD numbers and sometimes ILS (Israeli currency). and the symbol near the number value needs to change accordingly.

On the view mode of my component, I am using this:

```
<lightning:formattedNumber style="currency" currencyCode="{!v.record.CurrencyIsoCode}" currencyDisplayAs="symbol" value="100"/>
```

and it works perfect!

**PROBLEM**

In the `lightning:input` component the currency symbol is displayed according to the user's local currency and not according to the record's defined currency.

for example - this is how a field looks like when it's record is defined as USD, but it displays in ILS:

[image]

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to define the `lightning:input` component to change the currency symbol?

If not - what is the best approach to show the right symbol (I have the `CurrencyIsoCode` field in my code and can use it)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue here. I talked with Salesforce support about that almost a year ago, but they haven't provided a proper solution for that using the lightning:input component yet.

Note a single user would require to create records in multiple currencies. But apparently, Salesforce Lightning product developers failed to analyse that requirement.

The lightning:input component should include a currencyCode attribute that receives a currency ISO code and renders the value with the proper currency sign. I'm still waiting for that capability.

The work around is to use ui:inputCurrency and set the format attribute (i.e. £#,###.00), but if you have a form built using only lightning namespace components, then that will require additional effort to make ui:inputCurrency look and feel the same. You can also build your own component as well, but I guess you shouldn't be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks @OscarBecerra, eventually what I do is - not using the multiple currency feature of SF and just using a currency field, then I can use `<lightning:input type="number" formatter="currency" name="apiName" value="{!v.value}" currencyCode="{!v.currencyCode}" step="1" />` and set the currency code as I want